# Metabox does not show in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I am trying to create a metabox input field in a custom post type and it does not work even if I followed the instructions the best I could. I am not a PHP dev so I guess it could be just a small thing that is missing or it is wrong.

By not working I mean, I does not show at all in the WP UI.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

function add_post_type($name, $args = array()) {
    add_action('init', function() use($name, $args) {

            $upper = ucwords($name);
            $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ','_',$name));

            $args = array_merge(

            array(
            'public'=> true,
            'label' => "All $upper" . 's',
            'labels' => array('add_new_item' => "Add New $upper"),
            'support' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields'),
            'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','category')
            ),

            $args

            );

            register_post_type('$name', $args);
        });

}


//now we create and register a taxonomy
function add_taxonomy($name, $post_type, $args = array()) {
    $name = strtolower($name);

    add_action('init', function() use($name, $post_type, $args) {
            $args = array_merge(
                array(
                'label' => ucwords($name),

                ),
                $args
            );
                register_taxonomy($name, $post_type, $args);
    }); 
}

/************************************************************
  Now we add the names of the custom post type and taxonomies
*************************************************************/


add_post_type('snippet', array(
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields'),
            'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
));


add_taxonomy('language', 'snippet');

/************************************************************
  Creating Metaboxes
*************************************************************/

add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box(
        'er_snippet_info',
        'Snippet Info',
        'er_snippet_info_cb',
        'snippet',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
});

function er_snippet_info_cb() {
    global $post;
    $url = get_post_custom($post->ID); 

    ?>

    <label for="er_associated_url">Associated URL: </label>
    <input type="text" name="er_associated_url" id="er_associated_url" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" />

    <?php
}
    add_action('save_post', function () {
        global $post; 
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
        //security check 
        if ($_POST && !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['er_nonce'], _FILE_)) {
                if ( isset ($_POST['er_associated_url']) ) {
            update_post_meta($post->ID, 'er_associated_url', $_POST['er_associated_url']);  
            }
       }

    });
?>
```

The other issue is that the Tag is not named even if the function is there.

Comment: A question should not rely on a link to an external website. Put the code into your question please.

Comment: @toscho sorry about that, everytime i was adding the code was the editor was removing some part of it.

Answer (score 1):

The custom post type is being register as `name`, not `snippet` as is being called in `add_meta_boxes` action. This is because a PHP var is passed inside single quotes and it is not being interpreted.

Change this:

```
register_post_type('$name', $args);
```

To:

```
register_post_type($name, $args);
```

This also work:

```
register_post_type("$name", $args);
```

But never pass PHP variables inside single quotes if you want they be interpreted.

Also, it is recommended the use of `add_action('add_meta_boxes_{post-type}', 'callback')` to create less unnecessary hooks for other post types (from [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes)).

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you are trying to pass [functions as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700433/pass-function-as-parameter-in-php) in add_action(). That syntax works in javascript, but not so well in php.
Try doing it with passing the function name instead in add_action()

Comment: Lambda functions are working fine in PHP 5.3+.

Answer (score 0):

This may help. It worked for me

```
function my_plugin_add_meta_box()
{
    $type_name = array('custom_post_type_name');
    foreach ( $type_name as $custom_post_type ) {
            add_meta_box('my_plugin_meta_box_id', __('Meta Box Name'), 'my_plugin_meta_box_callback', $custom_post_type);
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_plugin_add_meta_box' );
```

and then you can add input boxes in the `my_plugin_meta_box_callback` function. Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

by default there will be no metabox for custom post typs.

Either you can add plugin like ADVANCED CUSTOM FIELD

or you can write a code for adding meta box to ur custom post types.

Clear reference site:

https://thomasgriffin.io/how-to-automatically-add-meta-boxes-to-custom-post-types/

// look at this link

add_meta_box( 'meta_id', 'My Custom Meta Box', 'tgm_custom_meta_box_callback', $post_type, 'normal', 'high' );